# Solve: $-2^x-x/2=0$ analytically

Tags: exponential-function, closed-form, lambert-w, lagrange-inversion

$-2^x-x/2=0$

I guess that the (only?) solution to this equation is $x=-1$. However, I do not know how to find this solution analytically.

Any help or hint is very much appreciated.

Edit: Thanks! Yes, there is only one solution that is $x=-1$. Now I am trying to understand how to derive this solution analytically. I basically want to, if possible, transform this equation so that it ends up saying $x=-1$. Probably using logarithms might help, but I have not found the way.

Comment: By "find it analytically", you mean something like the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1)?

Comment: Hint: $-2^x$ is a monotonically decreasing function.

Comment: Thanks! Never heard of the Lambert W function, I will check it out and see if it can help me. Thanks for the hint, I am thinking about it...

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite the equation as $2^x=-{1\over2}x$, you can see that you are trying to find where the exponential curve $y=2^x$ and the straight line $y=-{1\over2}x$ intersect.  Since the exponential curve is increasing (as $x$ increases) while the straight line, which has negative slope, is decreasing, the curves have at most one point of intersection.  Thus $(x,y)=(-1,{1\over2})$ is the sole point of intersection, i.e., $x=-1$ is the only solution to the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is equivalent to $2^{x+1}+x=0$. See what happens when you take the derivative...

Comment: I understand how you got there. Now I took the derivative and found that it is: $ln(2)2^(x+1)+1$. Not sure how to follow though. This cannot be equal to 0, right? What can it possibly be equal to? Or did you mean to do something different?

Comment: @Lorena_dok This is always $>0$. What does that mean about the zeroes of the function?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you mean! This implies that there can only exist one solution (the $x=-1$ in this case). My next question is: how can I find this $x=-1$ analytically? Is there a way to, for example, use logarithms on the equation so that it ends up saying $x=-1$?

Comment: @Lorena_dok I don't know of an analytical solution to these sorts of problems without the Lambert W function (the standard method of attack on problems such as this), but there certainly might be one I'm not aware of. Generally, though, in equations of the form $a^x+bx=c$, the solution is not very nice.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-$2^{x+1}$ is increasing from $0$ till $\infty$ and $y=-x$. There are consequently just one solution to $2^{x+1}=-x$ which is obviously $x=-1$

Answer (score 0):

$$-2^x-\frac{x}{2}=0$$

**1.) Solution as series**

To solve the equation analytically as a series, you can use Lagrange inversion.

**2.) No solution with elementary inverses**

The equation is a zeroing equation of an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

Powers with irrational exponents are transcendental functions. Therefore the equation isn't an algebraic equation, it's a transcendental equation:

$$-e^{\ln(2)x}-\frac{1}{2}x=0$$

Because $-e^{\ln(2)x}-\frac{1}{2}x$ is a polynomial of two algebraically independent monomials, the function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto -e^{\ln(2)x}-\frac{1}{2}x$ seems to have no elementary inverse. Therefore we possibly cannot solve the equation by rearranging it only by applying elementary functions (elementary operations) which we can read from the equation.

**3.) Solution in closed form with Lambert W**

The equation is solvable by applying [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). By some simple rearrangings, we can bring the equation into a form that is solvable by Lambert W:
$$-e^{\ln(2)x}-\frac{1}{2}x=0\ \ \ \ \ \ |\cdot(-1)$$
$$e^{\ln(2)x}+\frac{1}{2}x=0\ \ \ \ \ \ |-\frac{1}{2}x$$
$$e^{\ln(2)x}=-\frac{1}{2}x\ \ \ \ \ \ |\cdot e^{-\ln(2)x}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}xe^{-\ln(2)x}=1\ \ \ \ \ \ |\cdot 2\ln(2)$$
$$-\ln(2)xe^{-\ln(2)x}=2\ln(2)\ \ \ \ \ \ |\ W$$
$$-\ln(2)x=W(2\ln(2))\ \ \ \ \ \ |\ /(-\ln(2))$$
The only real solution is:
$$x=-\frac{W(2\ln(2))}{\ln(2)}.$$
$$x=-1,$$
because, if $a$ is a constant, $\ln(a)e^{\ln(a)}=a\ln(a)$ and therefore $\ln(a)=W(a\ln(a)),\frac{W(a\ln(a))}{\ln(a)}=1$.